# Consider 4 cases of water droplet, ie when water droplet is in sea, in glass, in air after rain, as humidity?

Tags: optics, visible-light, water, reflection, refraction

When water droplet is in air  as water vapours it scatters blue light, after rain by refraction dispersion and TIR it forms rainbow , in sea it scatters blue light while water in glass ( drinking glass  container)doesn't scatter blue light and water appears colourless.
Why there are these differences?
I am not sure this is a good question , but there must be some reason for these nature's of water droplet.
I think the factors like size , etc have a play

Comment: Water is blue, it's just something one wouldn't notice in very small amounts of water.

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't water colourless?

Comment: Yes I am sure, in fact it's such a weak color that water appears colorless on small scales.

Comment: Thanks ,@ triatticus